# Can't find variable: Symbol

Tags: react-native

I'm using create-react-native-app with expo's react-native v22.0.1. I've developed my app using the emulator, where it works properly. However, when I open it with the Expo app, I get a "Can't find variable: Symbol" error, occurring in *assembleStyles* (<strike>I've got no idea what that is</strike> that's just a function from the ansi-styles library, probably the error happens somewhere else).

I've tried importing babel-polyfill or es6-symbol to the first line of my App.js file (entrypoint), but with no success.

What can be going on here?

Edit: these are my dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore": "^0.1.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.1",
    "chai-enzyme": "0.8.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.0",
    "enzyme": "3.1.0",
    "ignore-styles": "5.0.1",
    "jest-expo": "22.0.0",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.6.2",
    "react-native-scripts": "^1.5.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.14",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "sw-precache": "5.2.0",
    "watchman": "^0.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-remove-nonjs": "0.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.2.0",
    "expo": "^22.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "prop-types": "15.6.0",
    "qs": "6.5.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "react-facebook-login": "3.6.2",
    "react-google-login": "^3.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "5.2.0",
    "react-images": "^0.5.11",
    "react-native":
      "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-22.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.3.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-native": "^4.2.0",
    "react-slick": "0.15.4",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^2.2.1"
  }
```

Comment: Can you include the list of your dependencies? I'm suspecting one of your dependency is using `Symbol` and I'm curious to know which one.

Comment: Done. However, shouldn't the use of babel-polyfill or es6-symbol fix that case?

Comment: @kytwb Found it. It's react-native-snap-carousel, using AnimatedComponent. Still haven't been able to make it work with a polyfill.